# Probabilties of a event to occurs when other events may prevent it

Tags: probability

I want to calculate the probabilties of a particular event to occurs following some conditions, but i do not know how to make the calculation.

**The datas :**
8 events {E1,E2,E3,E4,E5,E6,E7,E8}.
**The conditions :** 
E1 always occurs first,
E2,E3,E4,E5,E6,E7 and E8 occurs at random (but always one after another),
The events may affect one other event (if applicable), and may prevent the affected event to occurs,
E1,E2,E3 and E4 only affect E5,E6,E7 and E8,
E5,E6,E7 and E8 only affect E1,E2,E3 and E4,
if E5,E6,E7 or E8 was affected by E2, it cannot be affected by another event and it wil be prevented (unless the event already occurs),
if E5,E6,E7 or E8 was affected by two other event in whatever order, it cannot be affected by another event and it will be prevented (unless the event already occurs),
E1,E2,E3 and E4 will always occurs, even if affected by the 4 other events.

**Samples :**
Conventions : E1 -> E5, E2 -> E6 means that E1 occurs before E2 and affect E5, then E2 affect E6.

1. E1 -> E5, E2 -> E5, E3 -> E6, E4 -> E6, E7 -> E1, E8 -> E1 is a valid possibility because E2 affect E5 after E1, E5 was affected by E2 and cannot occurs, E6 was affected by two event and cannot occurs.
2. E1 -> E5, E5 -> E2, E2 -> E5, E3 -> E6, E4 -> E6, E7 -> E1, E8 -> E1 is a valid possibility because E2 affect E5 after E1, E5 was affected by E1 and E2 but can occurs because it was affected by E2 after, E6 was affected by two event and cannot occurs.
3. E1 -> E5, E5 -> E2, E6 -> E2, E7 -> E2, E8 -> E2, E2 -> E6, E3 -> E7, E4 -> E8 is a valid possibility because E5, E6, E7 and E8 was affected after they occurs.
4. E1 -> E5, E5 -> E2, E6 -> E2, E7 -> E2, E8 -> E2, E2 -> E6, E3 -> E6, E4 -> E8 is **not** a valid possibility because E3 affect E6, and it was already affected by E2.
5. E1 -> E5, E5 -> E2, E6 -> E2, E7 -> E2, E8 -> E2, E3 -> E6, E2 -> E6, E4 -> E8 is a valid possibility because E3 affect a E6 before it was affected by E2.

**The results :** 
I have programatically calculate the number of possibilities and the number of time E5 occured, wich give me the following result : **178.053.120/216.760.320** (or ~82.14% of chance that E5 will occurs). However, the method used was to calculate every possibilty, from 
E1 -> E5, E2 -> E5, E3 -> E5, E4 -> E5, E5 -> E1, E6 -> E1, E7 -> E1, E8 -> E1
to
E1 -> E8, E8 -> E4, E7 -> E4, E6 -> E4, E5 -> E4, E4 -> E8, E3 -> E8, E2 -> E8
and discarding the impossible cases.
This method is not really effecient (like the bubble algorithm).

**The objective :**
My primary objective is to understand how to obtain these results by calculation (with a pen, a piece of paper and a calculator).
My secondary objective is to implement these caculations into a algorithm.

**Precision on what i am asking**
What i am asking is the **methodology** to use wich will give me the computed result.
For example, i know that there is 5040 cases for the position in the timeline  of the events, and this result can be obtained by 7!.

In the same way, i know that there is 1/2 number of total cases that E5 occurs before E2, 1/3 that E5 occurs before E2 and E3, and 1/4 that E5 occurs before E2, E3 and E4, and this result can be obtained by 1/n where n is the number of events.

However, i do not know what i must use to obtain the previous result (178.053.120/216.760.320), nor what i should search to be able to resolve the problem.

Thanks for your time reading this.